# SQL - find all records where col like <pattern>

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find all the records in a table that match a pattern(actually a list of patterns).

> SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COL1 like '%number%';

number is a list, all values in a column of another table

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COL1 like '%<val>number</val>%';
```

I am getting a list ids from TABLE_A and I am trying to query TABLE_B whose column stores thousands of xml files. In these xml files I am trying to look for the pattern

```
<val>number</val>
```

where number is in the list of ids.

Comment: Yo need to be more specific.

Comment: Please provide the schema of you tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION ALL operator and basic join:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLENAME t
JOIN(
   SELECT '<val>123</val>' As pattern FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '<val>245</val>' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '<val>234</val>' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '<val>323</val>' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '<val>163</val>' FROM dual 
) p
ON t.col1 LIKE '%' || p.pattern || '%'
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a914f/2

---

EDIT

---

If there is another table that contains pattern values, the task is even easier, just:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLENAME t
JOIN AnotherTable p
ON t.col1 LIKE '%' || p.pattern || '%'
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0318/1

Comment: But I have thousands of records like <val>xxxx</val> in another table, how do i loop through them or an easier way?

Comment: @linoox I've updated my answer with an another example.

Comment: Thanks Kordirko. I have also updated my question, if that gives a better idea of the problem. I will try to modify your solution for my problem or rather modify the problem :). Using the ids I'll create a similar  pattern and store in temp table and use your solution.